# Is something wrong with a proof of $f(A) \cup f(B) \subseteq f(A \cup B)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Claim: $$f(A) \cup f(B)  \subseteq f(A \cup B)$$

Suppose $$ y \in f(A) \cup f(B)$$

$$y \in f(A)$$

or

$$y \in f(B)$$

$$\exists x_0 \in A (f(x_0) = y)$$

or

$$\exists x_0 \in B (f(x_0) = y)$$

So,

$$x_0 \in A \cup B$$

such that $$f(x_0) = y$$

Thus,

$$y \in f(A \cup B)$$

---

I have an actual proof of this, but I am not sure why the one above won't work. Please, see if it's correct.

Comment: This proof looks fine, except you should say "$\exists x_0 \in A \cup B$" towards the end.

Comment: The proof is correct, with a little fix: from $\exists x\in A(f(x)=y)$ you can deduce $\exists x\in A\cup B(f(x)=y)$ and similarly for the case $\exists x\in B(f(x)=y)$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof can be fixed as suggested in the comment by @egreg.
The problem with what you originally wrote is that the $x_0$ in

$$\exists x_0 \in A (f(x_0) = y)$$

is not necessarily the same as the $x_0$ in

$$\exists x_0 \in B (f(x_0) = y),$$

so it doesn't make sense to write

$$x_0 \in A \cup B$$

as if it somehow followed from those two facts.  In fact, it is problematic that you
suddenly removed the existential quantifier from $x_0$.